# Does Shadowrun Returns have random runs like Genesis's Shadowrun had?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

I'm playing Shadowrun Returns and just found my first Mr. Johnson. He gave me only one run and after that run there aren't any other runs.

Does Shadowrun Returns have random runs, like Genesis's Shadowrun do? Or are they "pre-made" and only offered at some points of the game, as a kind of sidequest?

Comment: @Sterno thank you, shadowrun-returns tag didn't existed before this question and I couldn't create it.

Comment: I think i'm pretty far into the game and I haven't found any randomly generated missions yet.

Comment: You're referring specifically to "Dead Man's Switch" I think, which does not have random runs. Neither does Dragonfall as far as I can tell. *Shadowrun Unlimited* is a user-mod focused on random runs (and even random encounters with LoneStar (the cops) as your notoriety increases and heat escalates!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I have played through the game and did not find any indication of random runs. I think this is to keep the difficulty throughout the game consistent without forcing the player to grind for Karma.

Comment: "Forcing"? I loved those random runs, and if they made the final boss easier for me, so much the better. :)

Comment: I like random runs, too, but (potential spoiler alert) the main story arcs of both Dead Man's Switch and Dragonfall feature time-oriented events that, while not actually implemented using game time, still gives the player a sense of an impending end-game, and doing unlimited random runs / karma grinding would probably detract from these particular modules.

Answer (score 4):

No there are no random runs. However, there are several DLC stuff (third party) you can download off of Steam Workshop that have random runs built in. Several of them are pretty open ended. Also there is a chance the new Berlin expansion will have random runs. So far that is one of the most important things missing from the game. Since the game is Modular I expect the developer to release many mods, plus many user mods to get released...so if there is nothing out there yet, there definitely will be. There was a user remake of the original Shadowrun that is going pretty well, it will definitely have some in it, if it doesn't already.

Comment: Shadowrun Unlimited is an excellent mod with random runs as the core focus. You also get different options for "bases" and can work with different "fixers" to get random jobs. It takes a little bit to get through the prologue and into the randomness, but it's worth it for this really well done user mod!